# PBKDF2 password Validation

Tags: php, database, cryptography, pbkdf2

I have a Keycloak database credential table that uses the PBKDF2 algorithm to store passwords and contains details related to the algorithm  like hash iteration,salt,value.
In my code I am using the PHP function 
hash_pbkdf2("sha256",$password,$salt,$iteration) to generate a hash. This function generates a hash bit it doesn't match the hash value stored in the Keycloak credential table.
How do I validate the password stored in the database to the one inputted by the user? I have no idea what is going wrong here. Any help would be helpful

Comment: How do you know that Keycloak uses SHA-256 PRF? And how many iterations? Looks like [SHA1](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b478472b3578b8980d7b5f1642e91e75d1e78d16/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/credential/hash/Pbkdf2PasswordHashProviderFactory.java) to me.

Comment: It's mentioned in the keycloak documentation and the iteration is set to 20000.

Comment: In theory - you may use KeyCloak's API (password grant token request) to validate the user's credentials